# Turning a form's GET into a PHP variable?

Tags: php, sql-injection

I'm trying to make the following form's GET function to be part of a predefined variable.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

---

Let me explain a little more of what I'm really trying to do. I currently run a website concentrating on the U.S. stock market. I've created an HTML form with a method=GET. This form is used like a search box to look up stock ticker symbols. With the GET method, it places the ticker symbol at the end of the URL, and I created a quotes.php page that captures this information and displays a stock chart based on what ticker symbol is keyed into the box. For the company names, I've created a page called company.php that declares all of the variables for the company names (which happens to be a $ followed by the ticker symbol). The file, company.php, is the only file included in quotes.php.

This is where this came in: ' . $$_GET["symbol"] . '

The above code changes the GET into the variable based on what was typed into the form. I've used "die" to display an error message if someone types something into the box that doesn't match a variable in the company.php page.

I've also added into the company.php page variables for each company that will display which stock exchange each stock is listed on. These variables begin with "$ex_". So, what I was trying to do was have the symbol keyed into the box appended to "$ex_" so that it would display the corresponding stock exchange.

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to have what is typed into the form added to "$ex_"?
2. Is this an insecure way to code something like this (can it be hacked)?

Thank you all!

Comment: PHP's "variable variables" are a code smell. Use a better data structure.

Comment: Are you referring to what I got to work, or what I'm trying to get to work? Thanks!

Comment: did you take a look at `extract` ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php It could help a bit and simplify your problem

Comment: I'm adding this as a comment instead of an actual answer so as not to sound *too* unprofessional but this reads as a beginner super-villain intent on taking on the US stock market.

Comment: I mean no harm with this. Just a way to display stock chart data for my users based on the ticker symbol they enter. The charts being used are from a site that allows (and encourages) embedding them into web pages, so no stealing.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than prefixing your variables and using variable variables (that are potentially insecure especially with user input), try this:

```
$ex = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    ...
);
if( !isset($ex[$_GET['symbol']])) die("Error: That symbol doesn't exist!");
$chosen = $ex[$_GET['symbol']];
```

Comment: I'm sorry for being such a noob, but could you explain why using variable variables for user input could be insecure?

Comment: If the name of the variable is left open to the user, they could potentially access variables you don't want them to. Of course, whether it's an actual vulnerability or not depends on how you use it.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Please read my original post again as I've made some clarifications. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Is this really the case though if all of these variable variables are prefixed with 'ex_'. If only ex_ variables were created and used in this manner how would they access variables that you didn't want them to?

Comment: If the only page I'm including into the PHP page contains the variables that begin with ex_, how would they get access to other variables?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach:

```
extract($_GET, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "ex");
```

Although it's better to use it like this just to make sure there is no security issues.

```
extract($_GET, EXTR_SKIP);
```

Answer (score 0):

[PHP's extract()](http://php.net/extract) does what exactly what you want, and you should specify "ex_" as the prefix you want.

However, there are security issues and unintended consequences to using such a function blindly, so read up on the additional paragraphs following the function parameters.

Answer (score -1):

Will the below achieve what you need?

```
$myGetVariable = $_GET['symbol'];
$ex_{$myGetVariable} = "Something";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$_GET['symbol'] = 'APPL';

if (!empty($_GET)) {
  foreach ($_GET as $k => $v) {
   $var = 'ex_'.$k ;
    $$var=$v;
  }
}

var_dump($ex_symbol);
```

APPL